# Cannot Make Binding to ZIndex from Another Element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make binding to the ZIndex of another element in WPF in the same `.xaml` file but it does not work.

The element to be bound.

```
<Border 
    x:Name="BubbleTop" 
    CornerRadius="5" 
    Background="#EBF5EB" 
    Padding="8,6" 
    BorderBrush="LightGray" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    Grid.ZIndex="3">
        <ContentPresenter />
</Border>
```

The element who initial a binding.

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="statusText"
    Margin="..."
    Foreground="{Binding ElementName=BubbleTop, Path=Grid.ZIndex, Converter={StaticResource ToggleColorConverter}}"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Text="..."/>
```

In the converter, it is set to change the Foreground color according to the ZIndex of the Border element.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int z = (int)value;
    if (z == 3)
        return "Red";
    else
        return "Blue";
}
```

But it does not work. Any hint?

Comment: Try returning a SolidColorBrush object instead of a string. The dependency property for Foreground expects a SolidColorBrush, and only allows string in the xaml which is then translated by the framework into a brush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converter you have would work fine, except that the `Path` for your binding is wrong. When binding to an attached property, you have to put the path in parens for the path to be parsed correctly.

That said, I don't think a converter really makes much sense here. You can use styling to address a simple toggle like this. This allows you to keep more of the view logic in XAML.

For example:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="statusText"
    Margin="..."
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Text="...">
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <p:Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
      <p:Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=BubbleTop, Path=(Grid.ZIndex)}" Value="3">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </p:Style.Triggers>
    </p:Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

(Note: you can omit the `p:` XML namespace for the `<Style/>` element. I include that only because the Stack Overflow code formatter gets confused when there's a plain `<Style/>` element in XML and won't format the XML correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your value converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  int z = (int)value;
  if (z == 3)
    return Brushes.Red;
  else
    return Brushes.Blue;
}
```

Comment: I have changed as what you suggest, but it doesn't work. The text color is still black.

Comment: @Casper: based on the little bit of code you posted, your `Foreground` color should always be either _blue_ or _red_, not _black_. If it's black, you have some other error in your code. While I don't prefer the use of a converter in this scenario, the answer above would address your specific need, except that your code also has a bug in the path. You can't bind to an attached property without putting the path in parens. See my answer to your question for an example of what I mean.

Comment: @PeterDuniho nice explanation and thanks for the extra information, will come in handy in the future.

Comment: Actually, I double-checked and I realized that the string-to-brush conversion _does_ happen at runtime. IMHO your converter is preferable to one that returns a string (why force the conversion if you can pass the right object easily?), but the only actual problem in the code was the binding path, not the converter.